# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in JMeter request

Tags: html, jsf, jmeter

Why im getting [this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Vsa.png) in POST request?

I'm trying to login with JMeter, but no matter i do it won't work.
I have Cookie Manager `HC4CookieHandler/standard`, Regular Expression Extractor too `jsfViewState/name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="(.+?)"` checked Main and sub-samples/Body.

But still in POST login i'm getting [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKZLB.png)

What i'm missing? Is it in regular expression value? javax.facesViewState has value `"-2918962836342094824:7411539759421041608"`, but doesn't range `"(.+?)"` should catch it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your request details it appears that you're sending `${jsfViewstate}` instead of the numeric value so your Regular Expression Extractor doesn't seem to be capturing it from the response for some reason. The reasons could be in:

1. Parent sampler doesn't contain the `javax.faces.ViewState` input, it comes in sub-samples. In that case you will need to switch Regular Expression Extractor scope to "Main sample and sub-samples"
2. Response markup assumes that "ViewState" input is broken into 2 lines so your single-line regular expression cannot match it.

Some suggestions:

- You can use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to see JMeter Variables values
- You can use "RegExp Tester" mode of the View Results Tree listener to test your regular expression against live response

  See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for hints on getting to the bottom of JMeter script issues.

---

You can consider using [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) as an alternative.

1. Add XPath Extractor as a child of the first request
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: `Main sample and sub-samples`
   - Check `Use Tidy`
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `jsfViewState`
   - XPath query: `//input[@id='javax.faces.ViewState']/@value`
3. Disable (or delete) your Regular Expression Extractor
4. Refer extracted value as `${jsfViewState}` where required

XPath Extractor Configuration:

[image: XPath Extractor Configuration]

Demo:

[image: XPath Demo]

Comment: I already switched to "Main sample and sub-samples", but still nothing.
And in debug mode i get this error http://prntscr.com/csityl
In RegExp Tester i can find viewStates values with `<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="([^"]+)".*/>` , but with XPath query can't.

Comment: Switch to `XPath Tester`, regular expression needs to be different

Comment: Now  i got only  javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException.The rest is same...